# Blu-ray Browsable Slideshow with background music

Tags: video, slideshow, blu-ray

I have 100 jpg images and 1 ac3 background music. I need create Blu-ray slideshow, without render still image to video. I read Blu-ray spec and on topic [5.2.1.1](http://blu-raydisc.com/Assets/Downloadablefile/bdj_gem_application_definition-15496.pdf) I see this issue.

I do not know, how to create it! What is software I need use for it and how!?
[Figure 5-13 – Example of Browsable Slideshow with background music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3WKY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using Adobe Encore. There has slideshow creator tool. You can use images and background music as I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study JavaME and Xlets.
I personally found the [HD Cookbook](http://hdcookbook.jovial.com/) very useful.
I use Netbeans to code and compile my Blu-ray JavaME Xlet projects. They just need to be compiled using -target 1.3 in order to be compatible. It is essentially just Java 1.3 with some additional API's for Xlet and BD-J.

I've made a project similar to the one you're writing about here: One that loads images from a webserver and displays as a slideshow.

One note though: Older Blu-ray players can't load from disc while playing a video or audio at the same time, without creating a hickup in the video or audio. Afaik this only applies to older players though.